# Finding the correct shape for tf.data.Dataset feeding into LSTM with Masking

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm doing a time series classification task and I'm having trouble finding the correct way to use `tf.data.Dataset`. I can create a working model using numpy arrays as in the code below (the data has already been pre-padded with zeros to a max length of 180):

```py
tf_data.shape, labels.shape
> ((225970, 180, 1), (225970,))
```

So I have 225970 instances of 180 time steps with 1 feature.
And I can fit the model as follows. This works fine and creates the appropriate output/predictions:

```py
model = keras.Sequential(
    [
         layers.Masking(mask_value=0, input_shape=(180,1)),
         layers.LSTM(16),
         layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
    ]
)

model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

model.fit(tf_data,  labels, epochs=5)
```

However, when I try the following using `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors`:

```py
tf_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors((tf_data, labels.astype(int)))

tf_dataset = tf_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1024).batch(64)

model_v1 = keras.Sequential(
    [
        layers.Input(shape=(180,1), batch_size=64),
        layers.Masking(mask_value=0),
        layers.LSTM(16),
        layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
    ]
)
model_v2 = keras.Sequential(
    [
        layers.Masking(mask_value=0, shape=(180,1), batch_size=64),
        layers.LSTM(16),
        layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
    ]
)

<model_v1 or model_v2>.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

<model_v1 or model_v2>.fit(tf_dataset, epochs=10, steps_per_epoch=30)
```

I'm met with the errors

```
model_v1 - ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_48 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (None, 225970, 180, 1)
model_v2 - ValueError: Error when checking input: expected masking_70_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (None, 225970, 180, 1)
```

Can anyone explain what I need to do to either my tensorflow Dataset or to my model to ensure it will work with the `tf.data.Dataset` and not just the numpy array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You should use `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices` instead**,

```
tf_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf_data, labels.astype(int)))
```

---

As per the official documentation of the method [`tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_tensors),

> `from_tensors` produces a dataset containing only a single element. To
> slice the input tensor into multiple elements, use `from_tensor_slices`
> instead.

While the official docs for [`tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_tensor_slices) says,

> The given tensors are sliced along their first dimension. This
> operation preserves the structure of the input tensors, removing the
> first dimension of each tensor and using it as the dataset dimension.
> All input tensors must have the same size in their first dimensions.

The `*.from_tensor_slices` method slices the input tensor and considers the given array ( the tensor in our case ) as 225970 data instances. This allows to call methods like `*.shuffle` and `*.batch()` which shuffle and batch data instances respectively.

We can understand this with an example. First let's generate some dummy data instances.

```
x = np.random.rand( 2500 , 180 , 1 )
y = np.random.rand( 2500 , 1 )
```

With `*.from_tensors`,

```
tensor_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors( ( x , y ) )
for sample in tensor_ds.take( 1 ):
    print( sample[ 0 ].shape )
    print( sample[ 1 ].shape )
```

The output is,

```
(2500, 180, 1)
(2500, 1)
```

And with `*.from_tensor_slices`,

```
tensor_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices( ( x , y ) )
for sample in tensor_ds.take( 1 ):
    print( sample[ 0 ].shape )
    print( sample[ 1 ].shape )
```

The output is,

```
(180, 1)
(1,)
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked and was a very good explanation.